# An issue while hosting laravel project in server(local and live)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, server, hosting

I want to host a laravel project in a dedicated server(aws, ubuntu 14.04).

So I placed the project in `/var/www/html`. When I go to `11.111.11.111/projectFolder/public` the default welcome page is showing up,

but when I move to `11.111.11.111/projectFolder/public/login`, I get an error - Page not found, interestingly  `11.111.11.111/projectFolder/public/index.php/login`, the login page is showing up but styles and jss files are missing.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://11.111.11.111/js/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

All these `css` and `js` files are present in `public` folder of laravel app.

These work perfectly when I run project using `php artisan serve`

The `.htaccess` file is as below,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I just want to change the `.htaccess` file, so when I type `11.111.11.111`shows the application as when run normally.

Comment: In you live server, what web server are you using? Apache or nginx?

Comment: am using `apache` 2.4.7

Comment: You shouldn't be using 'public' in the url. Where you define your virtualhost, set the root document to public. SOmething similar to `<Directory "/var/www/projectfolder/public">`. The reason it works with artisan serve is because artisan points automatically to the public folder so you dont have to enter it manually in the url. Also, place your folder directly in `/var/www/` as good practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see your project directly with http://11.111.11.111, you must change the `DocumentRoot` setting in your `httpd.conf` file.

In your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file, change the directory root to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projectFolder/public
```